# Swift Local Search MapView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm currently integrating local search into my iOS app, and I'm running into some problems. Everything is building fine with no errors, but the search function is just not happening. I've ran it on the simulator and on my iOS Device, and the function doesn't seem to be running. I've checked my console log and nothing is going through.

*italic**Edit: I've fixed the problem with the method not being called, but I'm now getting the following error. I can paste the whole call stack if needed

`"searchText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff2f1c1c3b0
2015-02-16 21:10:26.818 THINKStatus[60477:1795955] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[THINKStatus.loggedinViewController searchText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff2f1c1c3b0'"`

Here is the code for my view controller:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit

class loggedinViewController : UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchText: UITextField!
var matchingItems: [MKMapItem] = [MKMapItem]()

let service = "tgsLogin"
let userAccount = "tgsLoginUser"
let key = "RandomKey"


@IBAction func loggedinActionButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let error = Locksmith.deleteDataForUserAccount("tgsLoginUser", inService: "tgsLogin")

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("logoutViewSegue", sender: self)

}

@IBAction func textFieldReturn(sender: AnyObject) {
    sender.resignFirstResponder()
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    self.performSearch()
}

func performSearch() {

    matchingItems.removeAll()
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText.text
    request.region = mapView.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

    search.startWithCompletionHandler({(response:
        MKLocalSearchResponse!,
        error: NSError!) in

        if error != nil {
            println("Error occured in search: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else if response.mapItems.count == 0 {
            println("No matches found")
        } else {
            println("Matches found")

            for item in response.mapItems as [MKMapItem] {
                println("Name = \(item.name)")
                println("Phone = \(item.phoneNumber)")

                self.matchingItems.append(item as MKMapItem)
                println("Matching items = \(self.matchingItems.count)")

                var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = item.name
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    })
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.delegate = self


}


}
```

app delegate:

```
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?


  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that you may be somewhere using searchText as if it was a function. I don't see that in your code, so there are several possibilities:

1. You have some other code that uses it that you did not post
2. The binary is not in sync with the source code above
3. There is a bug in the framework

I would focus on the first two. Try reviewing all error messages to see if there is any indication of line in the code that fails. Try cleaning the project and rebuilding. Try searching for "searchText" in all your source files...

Comment: I tried checking the source code and there's no spot where I use searchText as a function.. What do you mean by checking if the binary is in sync with the source code?

Comment: What I mean by that is going to Windows -> Projects -> Derived Data -> Delete, which will remove all previously built files and next build will recreate them. This sometimes helps with weird problems. You might also try removing the control from the XIB or storyboard and your Swift file and recreate again. The way you use it in the code looks fine to me. Try finding the actual line where it is happening...

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me. The only differences I see is some question marks instead of exclamation points. Let me know if this works for you.

```
@IBAction func textFieldReturn(sender: AnyObject) {

    sender.resignFirstResponder()
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    self.performSearch()

}


func performSearch() {

    matchingItems.removeAll()
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText.text
    request.region = mapView.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

    search.startWithCompletionHandler({
        (response: MKLocalSearchResponse?,error: NSError?) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error occured in search: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else if response!.mapItems.count == 0 {
            print("No matches found")
        } else {
            print("Matches found")

            for item in response!.mapItems {
                print("Name = \(item.name)")
                print("Phone = \(item.placemark)")

                self.matchingItems.append(item as MKMapItem)
                print("Matching items = \(self.matchingItems.count)")

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = item.name
                annotation.subtitle = address
                self.mapAnnotations.append(annotation)
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: let's assume on a navigation app we want to show nearest or first gas station's distance while driving. How can i make sure that search results filtered so it only displays on route locations not the opposite side of way